# Replacing XML content with Regular Expressions and SED

Tags: regex, xml, bash, sed

I have a project that's effectively 2 maven projects.  In the "child" maven project I have a property that references the version in the parent project:

```
<myparent.project.version>15.0.0-SNAPSHOT</myparent.project.version>
```

What I'm trying to do is bash script a few common commands together, i.e. when creating a release branch I want to create one of the parent maven project, then update the child maven parent project but Im missing how to update this value:

I'm hoping to get something along the lines of working:
where newVersion = 16.0.0

```
$ sed -i "s/\<myparent.project.version\>[0-9.]+-SNAPSHOT\<\/myparent.project.version\>/<myparent.project.version>$newVersion-SNAPSHOT<\/myparent.project.version>/g" pom.xml
```

I have checked the regex (`\<myparent.project.version\>[0-9.]+-SNAPSHOT\<\/myparent.project.version\>`) with https://regex101.com/ and it matches the line I want to replace in my pom.xml file, but for some reason, I can't get the sed to work correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an xml parser like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). That said, for that simple substitution, you can try this GNU sed:

```
sed "s/<myparent\.project\.version>[0-9.]\+-SNAPSHOT<\/myparent\.project\.version>/<myparent.project.version>$newVersion-SNAPSHOT<\/myparent.project.version>/g" file
```

You must escape the one or more quantifier: `\+` and the dot: `\.` but not the `<` nor `>`(`\<` and `\>` are used for word boundaries with GNU sed)